# Cross-Join ItemGroups in MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, itemgroup

Given something like so..

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project DefaultTargets="test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ConfigFiles Include="*.config" />

            <DatabaseConfig Include="ABC">
                <Database>DB1</Database>
                <CsString>Database</CsString>
            </DatabaseConfig>

            <DatabaseConfig Include="DEF">
                <Database>DB2</Database>
                <CsString>Logging</CsString>
            </DatabaseConfig>
        </ItemGroup>


        <Target Name="test" >
            <!-- Some sort of join here (or somewhere)... -->
         <Message Text=" %(Combined.ConfigFile) %(Combined.Database) " />
        </Target> 
    </Project>
```

I'd like the Output to be something like this.. (given two files one.config & two.config)

```
one.config DB1
two.config DB1
one.config DB2
two.config DB2
```

(the order is not important, just the full cartesian product of the two ItemGroups)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems like a tidy solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ConfigFiles Include="*.config" />

        <DatabaseConfig Include="ABC">
            <Database>DB1</Database>
            <CsString>Database</CsString>
        </DatabaseConfig>

        <DatabaseConfig Include="DEF">
            <Database>DB2</Database>
            <CsString>Logging</CsString>
        </DatabaseConfig>
    </ItemGroup>

    <Target Name="test" >
        <ItemGroup>
            <Combined Include="@(DatabaseConfig)">
                <ConfigFile>%(ConfigFiles.Identity)</ConfigFile>
            </Combined> 
        </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text=" %(Combined.ConfigFile) %(Combined.Database) " />
    </Target> 
</Project>
```

Comment: This will not combine the item metadata in the way you wanted or produce the desired output. This will just output `DB1` on one line and `DB2` on another line. The answer I suggested allows for flexibility when combining metadata and will produce the outputs you asked for.

Comment: Ah, I see what went wrong when I tried locally: when I tried it I think the path to my sample configs was wrong. Yours provides the full path to the config instead of just the config filename/extension.

Comment: Hahaha, yours is the condensed answer after all. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is a way you can do this with minimal changes to your existing sample code. You can [combine metadata](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb651786.aspx) from `ConfigFiles` items and `DatabaseConfig` items into a new "combined" item and then output that "combined" item.

To combine the metadata, use [target batching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) with the batched target running once for each `DatabaseConfig` item. Then you can call another target to output the combined metadata to get the output you described. Take a look at my extension of your sample code to see how this would all be accomplished:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="test" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <ItemGroup>
    <ConfigFiles Include="*.config" />

    <DatabaseConfig Include="ABC">
      <Database>DB1</Database>
      <CsString>Database</CsString>
    </DatabaseConfig>

    <DatabaseConfig Include="DEF">
      <Database>DB2</Database>
      <CsString>Logging</CsString>
    </DatabaseConfig>
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="test" DependsOnTargets="test_setup;test_output" >
    <!-- Logic here runs after targets listed in "DependsOnTargets". -->
  </Target>

  <!-- This will run once for each "DatabaseConfig" item. -->
  <Target Name="test_setup" Outputs="%(DatabaseConfig.Identity)">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Specify the Database for the current DatabaseConfig item -->
      <CurrentDb>%(DatabaseConfig.Database)</CurrentDb>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <!-- Add a new CombinedOutput item with each run, combining metadata. -->
      <CombinedOutput Include=" %(ConfigFiles.FileName)%(ConfigFiles.Extension) $(CurrentDb) " />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="test_output">
    <!-- Output the combined metadata from the CombinedOutput items -->
    <Message Text=" %(CombinedOutput.Identity) " />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

What's happening in the sample:

1. The `test` target now just serves as a way to call two other targets to perform the work: `test_setup`, and `test_output`
2. The `test_setup` target is batched and creates the new
   `CombinedOutput` items.
3. The `test_output` target is called after `test_setup`
   to output the `CombinedOutput` items' metadata.

Output from `test_output`:

```
one.config DB1
two.config DB1
one.config DB2
two.config DB2
```

Comment: I should have more explicit, I need the two variables to be separate. The message is just to test, the actual variables will be used in an XmlUpdate step.

Comment: Well, yeah that would have been good to know up front. ;-) My suggestion answers your original criteria but does not focus on keeping those variables separate.