# MS Build Task not accepting properties

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I am trying to build my project using MSbuild. The solution builds perfectly fine if I hardcode the configurations

```
<MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionsToBuild.Identity)" Properties="Configuration=Debug" ContinueOnError="false"/>
<MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionsToBuild.Identity)" Properties="Configuration=Release" ContinueOnError="false"/>
```

but if I use batching like this  the values are not assigned

`<MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionsToBuild.Identity)" Properties="Configuration=%(ConfigList.Identity)" ContinueOnError="false"/>`

where ConfigList

```
<ItemGroup>
                <ConfigList Condition=" '@(ConfigList)' == '' and $(Configuration) != '' " Include="$(Configuration.Split(';'))" />
                <!-- parse all requested configurations into a list -->
                <ConfigList Condition=" '@(ConfigList)' == '' " Include="Debug" />
                <!-- if no configurations were specified, default to Debug -->
</ItemGroup>
```

and Configurations are provided from CLI
`msbuild build.proj -p:Configuration="Release;Debug"`

Also interestingly I am getting the value in
`<Message Text="Build for configuration %(ConfigList.Identity)"/>`

Whole Code

```
<Target Name="BuildApplication">
            <ItemGroup>
                <ConfigList Condition=" '@(ConfigList)' == '' and $(Configuration) != '' " Include="$(Configuration.Split(';'))" />
                <!-- parse all requested configurations into a list -->
                <ConfigList Condition=" '@(ConfigList)' == '' " Include="Debug" />
                <!-- if no configurations were specified, default to Debug -->
            </ItemGroup>
            <Message Text="Build for configuration %(ConfigList.Identity)"/>            
            <MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionsToBuild.Identity)" Properties="Configuration=%(ConfigList.Identity)" ContinueOnError="false"/>
            <!--<MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionsToBuild.Identity)" Properties="Configuration=Debug" ContinueOnError="false"/>-->
</Target>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks !

Sources referred:
[Using MSBuild to Build Multiple Configurations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5511274/using-msbuild-to-build-multiple-configurations)
[Passing properties to MSBUILD Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701157/passing-properties-to-msbuild-task)

Comment: What is the error message? Could you please share the whole error with us. Did your project all targets to `net core`? If so, try to add `Targets="restore;build"`, restore is needed. `<MSBuild Projects="%(SolutionsToBuild.Identity)" Properties="Configuration=%(ConfigList.Identity)" Targets="restore;build" ContinueOnError="false"/>`

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT this is the error message ```error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "|
Any CPU" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g
. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the def
ault solution configuration.```

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT we are not using .net core the solution would build on .net 472